Avoid LDAP login unless user is manually added to server
I have a PC with Ubuntu desktop 24.04.1 LTS joined to an Active Directory domain. I need to stop the login to that PC for any user that was Not manually added as a Ubuntu user. In other words, if a user does Not exist in that PC then that user should not be allowed to login in that PC even if LDAP credentials validation succeeds. How can this be done?. I created my AD domain and joined this domain following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT6O-TfJ41g
which is mentioned at:
https://www.considerednormal.com/2022/11/samba-based-active-directory-on-ubuntu-22-04/

How have you joined the Ubuntu system to AD? There are a few different ways of accomplishing that, and the tools that you're using will largely determine the appropriate solution.
